# How to extract the filename without the extension from a full path?

Tags: linux, bash, script, filenames, file-extension

I'm trying to right my first bash script, and at one point a filename is passed to the script as `$1`. I need to extract the file name without the extension.
Currently, I'm assuming that all extensions are three letters so I remove the last 4 characters to get the file name:

```
a="${1:0:-4}"
```

But I need to be able to work with extensions that have more than three characters, like `%~n1` in Windows.
Is there any way to extract the file name without the extension from the arguments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The usual way to do this in bash is to use parameter expansion. (See the [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page and search for "Parameter Expansion".)

```
a=${1%.*}
```

The `%` indicates that everything matching the pattern following (`.*`) from the right, using the shortest match possible, is to be deleted from the parameter `$1`. In this case, you don't need double-quotes (") around the expression.

Comment: The file patterns are generally like this: "Something.eng.ext". Obviously in this case ext is the extension, but using ${1%.*} will return only the "Something" part, right?

Comment: No. `${1%.*}` will return `Something.eng`. If you want to strip off everything to the right of the first `.` including the `.`, use `${1%%.*}`, which will return `Something`.

Answer (score 22):

If you know the extension, you can use [basename](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename)

```
$ basename /home/jsmith/base.wiki .wiki
base
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner in **Bash** without using **basename**:

```
$ s=/the/path/foo.txt
$ echo "$(b=${s##*/}; echo ${b%.*})"
foo
```